# What Method for one button and 3 text boxes

Tags: objective-c

I need to let a button know which text box is selected, i have tagged the text boxes 1, 2 and 3, I am new in this programming and I need to know if I am using the right methods and maybe  little help with the rest for this.
This is what I have so far:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    if (textField.tag == 1) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly check with your `textField's` outlet.

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
    if (textField == nameTextField) { //nameTextField is an outlet
         currentlySelected=@"nameTextField"
    }
    else if (textField == salryTextField) { //salaryTextField is an outlet
         currentlySelected=@"nameTextField"
    }
}
```

Two delegates

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField; // when gets focus
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField;   // when lost focus
```

You can create a `NSString *currentlySelected` and based on the method calls set the values in if-else.

Comment: Ok, but am I on the right way with this or is there other method to use.

Comment: @Sleeperinn: I think you can go ahead with this.

Comment: @Sleeperinn: Most welcome **Happy to help*, in return only few points :)